# have you ever extracted a stored encryption key from code

Tags: encryption, obfuscation

I been researching how best to store an encryption key in code.  The answers and advice many people give is that to not do it because it can be obtained from the code.  For example... http://bit.ly/16wpVU.

So my question is, have you ever done this?  Or at least have you done the technique required to do this but maybe for other purposes?  How exactly is it done so that if the decision is made to hide an encryption key in the code people can be better prepared for it if at all?

thanks
jose

Comment: I promise you, if you put the key anywhere in the executable, it **will** be found.

Comment: If you're on Linux or similar, a `strings <executable>` often already does the trick... More 'sophisticated' techniques can be broken with a debugger. Don't ever hardcode keys.

Comment: @emboss, do you know of cases of this happening?  What I am concered about is that people tend to just repeat what they hear on the Internet without actually being authoritative sources.  Do you know of a good article, book, anything that goes into details or goes over examples?

Comment: I remember having read a really good blog article about this, but unfortunately I haven't bookmarked it. But the thing with `strings` doesn't really require much convincing, for example try hardcoding a "secret key" in a Jar file or other executable of some sort, and then run `strings` on it - there it is. The debugger thing is not much more complicated - just monitor the application's memory access, at some point it will have to reconstruct and read the secret information. I bet there's a whole lot to be found in the scene around cracking keys/passwords for games, I'd start there.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I promise you, regardless of what protection you use, if somebody *really* ***really*** wants to break it, they **will**.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy  I'm not sure why you're paraphrasing my comment and directing it back to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was once doing compatibility testing for our Suite-B key negotiations vs Microsoft's and the resulting keys just didn't match for certain ciphersuites.

Using WinDBG, I was able to step through the disassembly, identify key entry points in their DLLs, find where the various key components were coming from, and figure out exactly where their code diverged from the rfc. (Oddly enough, it turned out that the rfc was in error.)

You certainly want to avoid putting the key in the code in the clear. I would suggest using a hash of some other data as your key.

After that, my worry is a guy with a debugger.

I'm sure there are others who have spent time thinking about how to make things undebuggable, but personally what I find difficult to debug is actions that happen in a different context: state machines that advance a little per execution, different processes, interrupt handlers, etc. It's tough to get a debugger in there when you can't insert a debug break in the source.

Comment: would throwing the key via an exception fit along those lines?

Comment: ...or would that just make it easier as an attacker can just set a breakpoint on the exception? Your first question, how to break in, I can answer. How to secure it gets into obfuscation, a field I'm not qualified to address.